# Timed out job hangs for 15 or 30 minutes and then runs

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, laravel-horizon

- Horizon Version: 3.7.2 / 3.4.7
- Laravel Version: 6.17.0
- PHP Version: 7.4.4
- Redis Driver & Version: predis 1.1.1 / phpredis 5.2.1
- Database Driver & Version: -

We are having strange errors with our Horizon. Basically this is what happens:
- A job is queued. And starts processing.

- After 90 seconds (our timeout config value) it times out.
- After 120 seconds (our `retry_after` value) job is retried.
- Retried job succeeds.
- After 15 minutes or 30 minutes, the original job(the one timed out) finishes. With running the actual job.

Seems like this can happen to any kind of job. For example if it's mailable that is queued, the user gets an email first, then 15 or 30 minutes later user gets another email. Same one.

Here our config files

`config/database.php`:

```php
'redis' => [
        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),
        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
    ],
```

`config/queue.php`:

```php
'redis' => [
    'driver' => 'redis',
    'connection' => 'default',
    'queue' => env('DEFAULT_QUEUE_NAME', 'default'),
    'retry_after' => 120, // 2 minutes
    'block_for' => null,
],
```

`config/horizon.php`:

```php
'environments' => [
    'production' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => env('HORIZON_CONNECTION', 'redis'),
            'queue' => [env('DEFAULT_QUEUE_NAME', 'default')],
            'balance' => 'simple',
            'processes' => 10,
            'tries' => 3,
            'timeout' => 90,
        ],
    ],
]
```

Here how it looks in Horizon Dashboard

This when the initial job times out. It stays like this in `Recent Jobs` while the retries are working.
[image: horizon1]

After almost half an hour it changes to this:

[image: horizon2]

It's the same tags, I just blacked out names.

Here are the logs we are seeing (times here are in UTC)

`[2020-04-22 11:24:59][88] Processing: App\Mail\ReservationInformation`

`[2020-04-22 11:29:00][88] Failed:     App\Mail\ReservationInformation`

`[2020-04-22 11:29:00][88] Processing: App\Mail\ReservationInformation`

`[2020-04-22 11:56:21][88] Processed:  App\Mail\ReservationInformation`

**Note**: With Predis we also see some logs like `Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://REDIS_HOST:6379]` but with PHPRedis there was none.

We tried a lot of different combinations, to eliminate the problem. And it happened in every combination. So we think it must be something with Horizon.

We tried:
- Predis with Redis 5 and Redis 3

- Predis with different `read_write_timeout` values
- PHPRedis with Redis 5 and Redis 3
- THP was enabled on one server. So we also tried all combinations with a server that has THP disabled.
- We were at Laravel 6.11 and Horizon 3.4.7 then upgraded to Laravel 6.14 and Horizon 3.7.2

There is only one instance of Horizon running. And no other queue is handled in this Horizon instance.

Any information or tips to try are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For us this turned out to be a configuration error in our systems. We were using OpenShift and Docker. We adjusted these values in our containers/systems

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time
```

and for now everything works normally.